# How to disable jQuery function for exact id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Using radiobutton for enabling/disabling select menu, but after implementing jQuery ui combobox to my select box, the following script doesn't hide jQuery ui select box. How to enable/disable jQuery ui combobox?

```
$(".parentcheck").click(function () {
    var selectedmenu = $("#menu").val();
    if ($(this).val() === "0") {
            $("#parent").closest(".ui-widget").find("input, button" ).attr("disabled", true);
        $("#parent").hide().find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');         
            $("#menu").change();
    }

    if ($(this).val() === "1") {
        $("#menu").change();
    }
});
```

Tried this line,

```
$("#parent").closest(".ui-widget").find("input, button" ).attr("disabled", true);
```

also

```
$("#parent").closest(".ui-widget").find("input, button" ).prop("disabled", true);
```

doesn't help

Answer (score 6):

Here's official documentation site jQueryUI:

Get or Set the disabled option, after init.

```
 // getter
 var disabled = $(".selector").autocomplete ("option", "disabled");
 // setter
 $(".selector").autocomplete ("option", "disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `attr("disabled", true);` should be `attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Comment: No, that will make absolutely no difference.  The "disabled" attribute is a boolean, so one truthy string is as good as another. In fact, the string (not constant) "false" also works :-)

Comment: Actually, it should be `.prop()` with a boolean instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

try this `find("input:[type=button]" )`